# How to pass current logged user in a form class in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a form where one field is a ModelChoicefield. Im trying to populate that field with objects from a different model. I have ran into a problem as i need to get the current logged user within the form to filter the queryset. Here are the 2 models

```
class UserExercises(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Muscle = models.ForeignKey(Muscle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Exercise(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(UserExercises, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
    reps = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)])
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here is my form

```
class AddExerciseForm(forms.Form):
    exercise = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserExercises.objects.filter(user=1))

    class Meta:
        model = Exercise
        fields = ['exercise', 'weight', 'reps', 'difficulty']
```

As you can see i am currently hard coding a filter in the ModelChoiceField, but want to replace that with the current users Id. Is there anyway of Going about this. Im new to django so any help would be Appreciated.

My View

```
@login_required
def add_exercise_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.user.id
        form = AddExerciseForm(user_id=user_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('myfit-home')
    else:
        form = AddExerciseForm()

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `AddExerciseForm` should extend `forms.ModelForm`.

To initialize form data based on some paramater, you can override `__init_` method of `ModelForm` to update form fields (that field is `exercise` in this case) based on some argument/parameter (which is `user_id` in this case).

```
class AddExerciseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Exercise
        fields = ['exercise', 'weight', 'reps', 'difficulty']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id', None)
        super(AddExerciseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user_id is not None:
            # update queryset for exercise field
            self.fields['exercise'].queryset = UserExercises.objects.filter(user=user_id)
        else:
            # UserExercises.objects.none() will return an empty queryset
            self.fields['exercise'].queryset = UserExercises.objects.none()
```

And pass the `user_id` while initializing the form in view:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # get user id
    user_id = request.user
    form = AddExerciseForm(user_id=user_id)
```

Comment: This seems like a good start. However, updating my form and view from you instructions, i am running into the error when attempting to open the form.    user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id')
KeyError: 'user_id'.
I am not sure if i am passing user_id right in the view :/

Comment: I've added a default for `kwargs.pop`. So, it'll return `None` if case you do not set it in view. This should avoid `KeyError`.

Comment: If you do not pass `user_id` while creating form, then you should not get anything in choice box. You probably missed this line. `exercise = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserExercises.objects.none())`.

Comment: @ThomasMichaelides I've updated the answer. Removed re-declaration of model field in the form.

Comment: I have added that and the form now opens fine. However, the choiceField does not have any content in it. This leads me to believe that the update query set in the __init__ is not happening which means that user_id is None. I am passing the user_id while initializing the form as you suggested. I even printed the value of user_id from the view to the console and was getting the correct value. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have  {exercise = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserExercises.objects.none())}

Comment: Can you log `user_id`, and check in database if there is actually any instances matching? Also notice `request.user` returns `User` object. You might want to use `request.user.username` or something similar.

Comment: I have done that and there is a matching instance. Maybe i wasnt clear in the original question. I am using the actual users id as the foreign key in the model, not the username?

Comment: Can you verify if `UserExercises.objects.filter(user=user_id)` query runs?

Comment: Yeah it does. It seems that user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id',None) is giving the result as None, meaning the fieldset will always return an empty queryset :s

Comment: Can you add your view code to the question? You probably are doing `AddExerciseForm(user_id)` in place `AddExerciseForm(user_id=user_id)` somewhere in your view.

Comment: I have added my view. Thankyou

Comment: This line is the culprit `form = AddExerciseForm()`. Change it to something like `form = AddExerciseForm(user_id=request.user)`

Answer (score 0):

override `__init__` method of the Form, and pass the user as argument

```
      def __init__(self,user,*args, **kwargs):
          self.user = user
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['exercise'].queryset= 
          UserExercises.objects.filter(user=self.user))
          self.fields['exercise'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
     class Meta:
      model = Exercise
      fields = ['exercise', 'weight', 'reps', 'difficulty']
```